# Hibernate inheritance - can't fetch only super entity in jpql query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have base entity - UserEntity with inheritance : joined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode()
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    //other fields
    }
```

and chield entities: AdminEntity, PartnerEntity, ClientEntity.

For example ClientEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class ClientEntity extends UserEntity {
//other fields
}
```

And i have queries where  I don't need to know what type of user I'm working with.
For clarity, you can provide functionality when you want reset the password. You need to find user and create password reset token.
In jpa repository i have simple method to find user by email

```
  Optional<UserEntity> findByEmail(String email);
```

But I see that hibernate does 3 left joins to find out what type of user I'm dealing with.
How can I fix this and get only the base class? I'am trying to add to UserEntity this annotation:

```
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
```

but it doesn't work.
When i tries to write query like this

```
 @Query("select u from UserEntity u where type (u) = UserEntity and u.email = :email")
    Optional<UserEntity> findByEmail(@Param("email")String email);
```

But I always get null.
 I know that I can change my strategy to SINGLE_TABLE, but in queries of this type, all fields will be fetched from the database which I don't need.
 Any ideas?

Comment: This is the problem with inheritance on Hibernate. You just can't query a `UserEntity` without LEFT JOIN with ClientEntity and others "childs" of `UserEntity`, because Hibernate expects that you can, any moment, do a `cast` from UserEntity to some of his childs. Inheritance with `JOINED` is a kind of EAGER

Comment: @Dherik It is very strange. Even if I use a strategy **SINGLE_TABLE**, from the database will fetched in my case about 40 fields, but i need only 6 from the basic user. This, of course, is better than 3 joins, but I would like a better solution. To alter all requests of this type to native ones is not very desirable, the sense of ORM is lost.

Comment: Maybe someone has some solution that I don't know. But try to not use inheritance on hibernate. Composition is a better choice, like "client has a user"